# python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 has dict syntax error for installed ackage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.5, python-importlib

I'm struggling to understand this problem with python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 with importlib_metadata package

```
An error has occured in the execution of the program. Error Message: invalid syntax (__init__.py, line 88)
Stack Trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata
ImportError: cannot import name 'metadata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata as metadata
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 88
    dist: Optional['Distribution'] = None
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This *importlib_metadata* was installed:

```
pip3 install importlib-metadata --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages 
(3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- 
packages (from importlib-metadata) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from 
importlib-metadata) (3.4.0)
```

Could anyone give some help to bypass this problem?

Comment: The installation location of the package suggest that you have installed it manually. You should uninstall it or downgrade it. At least that version is not compatible with Python 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

This got me today, very annoying issue.

Python 3.5.2, Ubuntu Xenial

One of the packages I was installing had a dependency of `importlib-metadata`, but the version wasn't pinned so I ended up with v3.7.0. This caused a problem, as [v3.0.0 of importlib-metadata requires Python 3.6 or later](https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v3-0-0).

However, I was able to `pip3 install importlib-metadata==2.0.0` and then continue installing my other packages. This should work provided the package you are trying to install is compatible with `2.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

This package *importlib-metadata* is imported from a package *jsonschema* which I use, so I removed this dependent package of *jsonschema* package, and it works.

```
pip3 uninstall importlib-metadata
```